# Can the use of the present progressive with the adverb "still" convey annoyance or surprise?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Can the use of the present progressive with the adverb *still* feel like an expression of annoyance or surprise? For example:

> I started teaching three years ago, and **I am still teaching**.

If it conveys none of that, than what would be the difference between the original sentence and the following?

> I started teaching three years ago, and I **still teach**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyance and surprise are inferred from tone.

While the use of the present progressive with the adverb "still" can deliver the required tone, it is not a guarantee that the tone of annoyance or surprise is present.  Other queues are necessary to validate that annoyance (or surprise) was being expressed.

For example, I'm still typing.  And I assure you I'm not annoyed, or even surprised by my typing.

Now some might read annoyance into my statement, but that's a problem of communication, which is how a message is received.  I can give hints (as I did with my assurance) and improve how my message is received; but, absent these hints, the reader will receive the message according to their past experiences and beliefs.